# System not seeming to read DVD

Tags: mount, dvd

As of yesterday, this laptop was able to play DVDs.
As of today, it no longer plays DVDs.

In gnome-disks, it seems to recognize the drive.

When running lshw I get this

> *-cdrom
> description: DVD-RAM writer
> product: DVD RAM UJ8B2
> vendor: hp
> physical id: 1
> bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
> logical name: /dev/cdrom
> logical name: /dev/cdrw
> logical name: /dev/dvd
> logical name: /dev/dvdrw
> logical name: /dev/sr0
> version: 1.00
> capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
> configuration: ansiversion=5 status=open

When I try playing the DVD with VLC, again this was working yesterday, it just tells me it could not open the disc, unable to open the MRL, etcetera.

This is probably related.  The DVD drive does not open by pressing the button, using the eject option in gnome-disks also doesn't open it.  I have to manually open (laptop) with a paperclip.  If the disc drive has unexplicably broken overnight though, would the drive still be recognized according to lshw?  I have tried restarting the system and nothing changed between boots.

Comment: The last line of `lshw`, `status=open` may show that the "drawer closed" microswitch is bad. Probably because you poked a paperclip into it too many times. Replace the drive.

Comment: Okay, so assume it is the drive that is bad.  Unfortunate.  It stopped working before I started poking a paperclip though, I only had to use the paperclip once it started refusing to recognize the disk and open.